# How to translate a message/variable in Django templates?

Tags: django, internationalization, django-templates, translation

I have `messages.success(request, 'sign-up-success')` in my view (I wrote a generic name, as I'm going to translate it later anyway), and display it with {{ message }} in my template. I want to be able to translate, so I tried `{% blocktrans %}{{ message }}{% endblocktrans %}` but this will translate *any* message, whether it's 'sign-up-failed' or whatever, to the msgstr I define in my django.po file.

How do I translate a message, which is a variable?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pointed it out: you can not translate a variable.

You have to translate the text where you define it:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
messages.success(request, _('sign-up-success'))
```

Then follow the standard translation process : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/

Comment: You sir are awesome. It worked. I had no idea you could do that. It even makes more sense as I'll see the text that needs to be translated right away when I browse my app views.

Answer (score 0):

Important thing is to have proper order in middleware in settings.py

```
  MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    )
```